# bootstrap right column with background

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm a bootstrap newbie user, so if it is a stupid question I'm sorry with you!
I'm trying to turn-off the background from the last right *col* but I'm not able to do this.
You can see the picture; I would like to hide the grey above the red rectangle..

[picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XMkI8.jpg)

Here is the code:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-11 col-lg-offset-1">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-11 news">
                    <h2>NEWS</h2>
                </div>
            </div>
        <div class="row news">
                <div class="col-lg-3">
                    <h3>Title</h3>
                </div>
            <div class="col-lg-4">
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
                        tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
                        quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
                        consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
                        cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
                        proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-4">
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
                        tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
                        quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
                        consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
                        cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
                        proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-1"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[Here is the code on an online editor](http://www.bootply.com/7KYRyrxv6y)

Thank you in advance!

Comment: the fragment you gave works correctly for me.  Maybe if you gave us something on an online editor that demonstrated the problem

Comment: I have added link to the online editor.. thanks :)

Comment: Johnathon Blakey and Chihab JR have both answered your question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved editing the number of "mother"-row column and its nested items: http://www.bootply.com/vcMjA3iMA5

Answer (score 1):

so if you want to hide that little white area
change `col-lg-11` to `col-lg-12` :

```
<div class="col-lg-12 news">
     <h2>NEWS</h2>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you fill the space?

```
<div class="col-lg-12 news"> <h2>NEWS</h2> </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like:

```
<div class="col-lg-1 no-background"></div>  // added class
```

CSS:

```
.no-background { background: none; }
```

Comment: I cannot enlarge columns to 12 cause  above it there are other col-lg-11 rows.. The background is related to the row, not to the col-lg-1. Now I'm writing from the phone, tomorrow I'll post code on an online editor.